# Shader working on my laptop, but not on my desktop

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, shader, fragment-shader

I already posted this question on unity answers yesterday, but maybe anyone here can help? I've been trying to do some stuff that involves getting an image from a native plugin (in the form of a .dll file). I load the image data into a native buffer and then push that to the gpu in the form of a structured compute buffer. From there, I display the image using a shader (basically just doing something like `uint idx = x + y * width` to get the correct index). And this works great on my laptop (ignore the low resolution, I lowered it to be able to inspect the values for each pixel; this is exactly how it's supposed to look).

[image: working]

But when I try it on my desktop, all I get is this mess:

[image: broken]

It's clearly displaying something, I'm almost able to make out contours of the text  (it doesn't seem like I'm just getting random noise). But I can't seem to work out what's wrong here.

So far I've tried:

- syncing the code across the two devices (it's excactly the same)
- changing the unity version (tried 2020.3.26f1 and 2021.2.12f on both machines)
- updating the graphics drivers
- checking the directx version (DirectX 12 on both)
- changing the editor game window resolution
- comparing the contents of the buffer (the `ComputeBuffer.GetData` method is getting the same completely valid values on both machines)
- building the project on both machines (both builds are working on my laptop and broken on my desktop)

Especially the last point really confused me. I'm running the same executable on both machines and it's working on my laptop with integrated graphics (not sure wether that could be relevant) but not on my desktop with a more modern dedicated gpu? The only idea I have left is that there might be some kind of optimization going on with my desktop's amd gpu that's not happening on my laptop's intel gpu. Any ideas on what I could try in the radeon software? Maybe it could even be some sort of bug (with unity or with my graphics driver)?

I'd be more than happy about any ideas on what could be the problem here (cause I have no clue at this point). And sorry if my grammar is a bit off at times, not a native speaker.

EDIT: Here's the shader I use to display the image.

```
Shader "Hidden/ReadUnpacked"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
        SubShader
    {
        // No culling or depth
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            static const uint PACKED_SIZE = 3;
            static const uint PIXELS_PER_PACK = 4;
            static const uint BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 8;
            static const uint PERCISION = 0xFF;     // 0xFF = 2^8

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            struct packed4
            {
                uint p[PACKED_SIZE];
            };

            struct unpacked4
            {
                fixed4 p[PIXELS_PER_PACK];
            };

            StructuredBuffer<packed4> InputBuffer;
            uint ImgIdx;
            float2 Resolution;
            float2 TexelOffset;

            fixed unpackSingle(packed4 val, uint idx)
            {
                uint pid = idx / PIXELS_PER_PACK;                   // pixel index
                uint sid = idx % PIXELS_PER_PACK * BYTES_PER_PIXEL; // shift index

                return ((val.p[pid] >> sid) & PERCISION) / (half)PERCISION;
            }

            unpacked4 unpack(packed4 packed)
            {
                unpacked4 unpacked;
                half r, g, b;
                uint idx = 0;

                [unroll(PIXELS_PER_PACK)] for (uint i = 0; i < PIXELS_PER_PACK; i++)
                {
                    fixed4 upx = fixed4(0, 0, 0, 1);

                    [unroll(PACKED_SIZE)] for (uint j = 0; j < PACKED_SIZE; j++)
                    {
                        upx[j] = unpackSingle(packed, idx++);
                    }

                    unpacked.p[i] = upx;
                }

                return unpacked;
            }

            fixed4 samplePackedBuffer(float2 uv)
            {
                int2 tc = float2(uv.x, 1 - uv.y) * Resolution;
                uint idx = tc.x + tc.y * Resolution.x;      // image pixel index
                idx += Resolution.x * Resolution.y * ImgIdx;
                uint gid = floor(idx / PIXELS_PER_PACK);    // packed global index
                uint lid = idx % PIXELS_PER_PACK;           // packed local index

                packed4 ppx = InputBuffer[gid];
                unpacked4 upx = unpack(ppx);
                return upx.p[lid];
            }

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = samplePackedBuffer(i.uv);

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After all those years DX12 can still be quirky on Unity. Could you check if DX11 works as expected on both platforms?

Comment: When checking the DirectX version, I just looked at what `dxdiag` reported. I wasn't even aware that you could change that in unity (completely new to this kind of stuff). I of course immediately tried all available options :) Oddly, everything but DirectX seemed to work (same broken result with `Direct3D11` and `Direct3D12`, but it worked perfectly with `OpenGLCore`, `OpenGLES3` and `Vulkan`). Thank you so mutch, maybe you could post this as an answer so that I can mark it as checked? And are there any caveats with switching to any of the three above? Can I expect a difference in performance?

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that I'm only targeting PC's for the time being (I think there's a pretty big difference on mobile).

Comment: I've found some comparisons now and it seems to me that `Vulkan` is comparable with `DirectX` when it comes to performance, with `OpenGL` being a bit slower. Would you agree with that?

Comment: Added the answer so that you can mark it. In my humble opinion OpenGL is on its way out as far as games are concerned. You may want to support it on older android devices. Other than that it's all but 'obsolete'. I put obsolete in quotes because it will probably still be useful for some things like getting to know 3D programming as it's relatively easy compared to, say, Vulkan.

Comment: Another obvious thing would be posting the source code of the shaders you're using together with the supporting CPU code. Most importantly how you create your buffers (Sizes and Strides). Someone may notice something.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, but I think the whole buffer part is fine (already struggled with the whole stride thing for quite some time). I was using it for quite a while and only just now got problems with my new gpu. I already noticed weird behaviour when using a [ByteAddressBuffer](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-byteaddressbuffer?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (randomly reading zeroes for some pixels). So I think it's just that these buffers do weird things at times (propably because they're not really meant for reading different values for different pixels).

Comment: If you don't feel like showing your code then no one will convince you. That said you should remember that just because some APIs and Unity's support for them can be quirky doesn't mean your code can't be buggy.

Comment: I just figured it would add unneccesary detail and make it harder to understand my question. But thanks for taking the time, I would of course be glad if you have any ideas on how to improve it.

Comment: I get the image in the form of a byte array (with the dimensions `width*height*3`, using RGB channels). I then just set the compute buffer (with `stride: sizeof(unit))` and a size of the original size divided by sizeof(uint)) to that array in C#.

Comment: `unit`?? Do you perhaps meant `uint`? How do you define that buffer on the shader side and how do you read from it and / or write to it?

Comment: Yeah, uint, I corrected it. As you can see in the updated question (forgot to mention that, sorry), I read 4 pixels at a time and then use bit shifting to "unpack" them. Most straightforward would probably be to just load all bytes into a texture, but that would mean everything being copied multiple times on the CPU side. The way I'm doing it now, I can just allocate memory in the native plugin and then directly copy that to video memory.

Comment: And as of right now, the CPU is clearly the bottleneck in my application. So I'd rather have the GPU do a little more work than unnecessary occupying the CPU. I guess this is a pretty neeche scenario.

Comment: You definitely don't do yourself any favors  writing all this instead of using Raw byte buffer. I would rewrite this using Byte buffer and since you said you saw some incorrect zero reads this leads me to believe you didn't specify the `ComputeBufferType.Raw` flag when creating that input buffer. Can you verify that?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. Sadly, I messed around with this for quite some time (and tried the raw compute buffer type) earlier but never ended up getting it working. I'll definitely try again with Vulkan though, maybe it'll fix that as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check all other 3D APIs (D3D11, Vulkan, OpenGL,...).

Comment: Thanks again, I think I'm going to go with `Vulkan` for now.